# Accidentally deleted xcode project files via Git commands

Tags: xcode, git, missing-data

I accidentally deleted all my files by committing a new build, then deleting that commit. (git commit -m, git reset -hard HEAD^). Then I tried to use (git merge ) to undo the delete. I noticed that all the missing files were back, but all the contents were missing.  To clarify, all the files that were missing after I deleted the commit was back, but contents of those files only included default Xcode markups and all my coding was still missing. Is anyone familiar with an issue like this? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated..

Steps:

1. git commit -m
2. git reset -hard HEAD^
3. git merge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use git fsck to see any dangling blobs or commits which remain after a reset.

```
git fsck --cache --no-reflogs --lost-found --unreachable  HEAD
```

You'll see something like this with any dangling objects:
[image]

Then just do git show with the blob id to inspect

```
git show fd2274ea24e214457fa865e6aa74a0a1b036291a
```

If it's the file you want, you can then write it to a file using git show {blob id} > filename.  e.g.

```
git show fd2274ea24e214457fa865e6aa74a0a1b036291a > test.txt
```

Comment: Ah thank you so much, I've previously inspected all dangling blobs with "git fsck" but never saw the unreachable blobs your solution has shown. I'll go ahead and inspect the blobs, and even if nothing shows up this answer is as good as it's going to get. I sincerely appreciate your help!